# Problems with adding inmobi SDK to my iOS project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob

I am using adMob mediation as my banner provider and it woks just fine. Now I want to add inmobi to the mediation and are following instructions but when trying building to my iPhone I get these errors?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:
      _getIMPublicKeyWithCert in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
      _getIMPublicKeyWithCert in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:
      _getIMPublicKeyWithCert in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecKeyGetBlockSize", referenced from:
      -[IMCommonUtil EncodeRSA:publicKey:] in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:
      _getIMPublicKeyWithCert in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecKeyEncrypt", referenced from:
      -[IMCommonUtil EncodeRSA:publicKey:] in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      _getIMPublicKeyWithCert in libInMobiCommons-3.6.5.a(IMCommonUtilPrivate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have added the libAdapterInMobi.a to the "Linked frameworks and Libraries" and added the SDK in a folder called inMobi. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, so if anyone can tell me or guide me I would be the happiest man alive! ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added all the correct frameworks outlined at http://developer.inmobi.com/wiki/index.php?title=IOS.

It looks like you might not have linked the `Security` framework specifically?